# What language(s) can I use in LibreOffice for macro scripting?

Tags: python, scripts, libreoffice

Not finding any info online; I hope somebody here knows. It was Python in OpenOffice; is it still Python? Or are they moving to *gasp* VBA?

Comment: Nothing change, Python is still there

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think [this page](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Scripting) answers your question. In summary, you can use the following:

- LibreOffice Basic
- JavaScript
- BeanShell
- Python

But you can't write/edit Python scripts from LibreOffice IDE, just to run scripts.